# Is there a way to read data from excel and set global variable in SOAP UI and send those global variable in request payload?

Tags: soapui

Is there a way to read data from excel set global variable in SOAP UI and send those global variable in request payload and how to call multiple rest services?

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely. You can use a Groovy test script. Use Apache-POI to read the spreadsheet, and store values in SoapUI properties, e.g.:

```
testRunner.testCase.setPropertyValue("MyProperty", "MyValue")
```

Then, in the XML request, parameterise it with:

```
<SomeNode>${#TestCase#MyPropName}</SomeNode>
```

You can have your Groovy test script loop over the spreadsheet and call e.g. a test case for each record:

```
def soapTestStep = testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName("SOAP Request1").name
testRunner.runTestStepByName(soapTestStep)
```

The second part of your question I don't have an answer for.